# Handle EntityNotFoundException when saving parent entity with removed child entity from collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My problem is simple, but yet finding the solution has become a rather tedious and difficult task.

I have two hibernate entities,

1. `Owner`
2. `Dog`

The `Owner` (or the "parent" entity) has three fields,

1. `name`
2. `address`
3. `dogs` (a collection of `Dog` entities - `OneToMany` relationship).

When removing a `Dog` from the `Owner`'s collection (both from the object's collection and from the database via the Dog Repository), as well as updating the address of the Owner, and then trying to save the updated object in the database, the following Exception is thrown:

`javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find project.pets.entities.Dog with id 10`

One way of working around the problem is to get the new version of the `Owner` once the `Dog` collection is updated, by calling the Owner's `Repository` with `findOne(ownerId)`, before updating the owner's address and saving the entity in the database.

But this does not seem like a proper solution.

I ought to mention that there is no caching implemented.

Has anybody come across such a thing and managed to handle it appropriately?

EDIT 1:

### Sample code:

### Owner:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner {

...

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner", 
           cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Dog> dogs;

...
```

### ==================================================

### Dog:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
public class Dog {

 ...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private Owner owner;

...
```

### ==================================================

### Example code:

```
Owner owner = ownerRepository.findOne(ownerId);
Dog firstDog = owner.getDogs().get(0); // getting the first dog of the owner

owner.getDogs().remove(0); // removing from object's collection
dogRepository.delete(firstDog); // removing from DB

owner.setAddress("new address");
ownerRepository.save(owner);
```

Comment: Please, post the sourcecode of your entities. It's hard to tell what's going on if you don't show us the classes (and more important, the annotations you used)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to execute `dogRepository.delete(firstDog);`: Owner already takes care of propagating the removal of your entry from DB. Which is the reason why you have the exception: `firstDog` was already being removed by Hibernate, so when you call `dogRepository.delete(firstDog);` again, Hibernate will complain because it cannot find your entity.

Comment: I don't quite agree with you. 

The owner will take care of its children's state if the cascade type is set to PERSIST. But that is not the case. 

Moreover, in the explanation above it is stated that the exception is thrown when the owner is saved (the last line)  and not when the dog is deleted from the database.

Comment: My bad, my eye got caught from the blueish `delete`, and focused on the code. Usually you better keep it simple and use ALL, unless you have a _very valid_ reason do not do so: in our Company, we're dealing with composition of lots polymorphic types and still, we do not invoke `xyzRepository.delete()` on each member variable but rather, let Hibernate do it for us.

Comment: Yes, the cascadeType.ALL (or more specifically cascadeType.PERSIST) will do in the general case scenario. 

The problem is, I have to refrain from using the ALL type because the project demands it.